# Label inside of UICollectionReusableView is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a custom UICollectionReusableView, HeaderCollectionReusableView, that I'm using in my code. And it in turn contains a UILabel. When I go to use the label it is nil for some reason. I first register the class and then I try and call it with a dequeue. What am I missing?

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.register(HeaderCollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: colReusableViewIdentifier)

    self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
}

@objc override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    let headerReusableView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: colReusableViewIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HeaderCollectionReusableView
    headerReusableView.headerLabel.text = "Reacshn"

    return headerReusableView
}
```

Comment: It ended up that explicitly registering the HeaderCollectionReusableView was causing the nil label issue. In my case simply cleaning the project and rebuilding without the register call worked.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at code i assume that the custom reusable view is not created using xib. The best option would be

1. Create a custom reusable view using xib.
2. Register in viewDidLoad using the following function i.e `func register(_ nib: UINib?, forSupplementaryViewOfKind kind: String, withReuseIdentifier identifier: String)`